# How to clear date and time on reset button

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am using two button s Date and Time .They are working well . but i need to add more button Clear . on click of clear button my Date N Time button should be empty (No date N Time should be display).

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_qs_date"
    style="@style/Text.Medium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Thu, 15/03/2012" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_qs_time"
    style="@style/Text.Medium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="11:00 AM" />

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/reset_date_time"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_reset_button" />
```

and my java code is:-

```
case R.id.btn_reset_radio_test_grp:

    rgYes.setChecked(false);
    rgNo.setChecked(false);
    break;

case R.id.reset_date_time:

    //i will have to write here
break;
```

Comment: are you saying you need to make your buttons show no text when the clear button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn_qs_date.setText("");
                    btn_qs_time.setText("");
                }
            });
```

Where clearButton is your `clearButton` in your UI